# XAML GridRow doesn't scale automatically when ErrorTemplate is displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, errortemplate

I have a XAML window with a TextBox, and this TextBox has an ErrorTemplate.

The ErrorTemplate is shown below, and as you can see, I have an AdornedElementPlaceholder, followed by a textbox whose Text field is bound to the ErrorContent:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationErrorTemplateTextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="AdornedElementPlaceholder" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=AdornedElementPlaceholder, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" 
                    FontSize="10"
                    Background="Red"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Padding="2" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding SendMessage}"
                    Text="{Binding AutoMessageSubject, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Style="{StaticResource StyleBase}"
                    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplateTextBlock}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

This works fine, except for one thing: the TextBox is inside a GridRow, with a Height="Auto". The row scales itself based on the textbox, but when the ErrorTemplate appears, with an extra TextBox on the bottom - the GridRow doesn't scale up to contain the new TextBox, and the new TextBox overlaps the elements below it.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[Validation.ErrorTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate(v=vs.110).aspx): Gets or sets the ControlTemplate used to generate validation error feedback on the **adorner layer**.

This means that if you use `Validation.ErrorTemplate`, the validation errors are displayed on the layer **above** usual content, so the "second" TextBlock is displayed over the grid, not within the grid cell.

I would implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` instead of semi-obsolete `IDataErrorInfo`, use a custom textbox style, and bind the visibility of the second TextBlock to `HasErrors` property. The example below uses a ToolTip instead of the second TextBlock:

```
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget}">
                                <ItemsControl DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}" />
                            </ToolTip>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you. I'll test this in a little while.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding Row/Column Definitions:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Add them to what? The control template?

Comment: the surrounding <Grid></Grid>